Automatic method to verify ros2 package compatability with new version
I am considering upgrading to ros2 jazzy from humble but would first like to verify all packages I depend on are supported.
Is there an automatic way to check that all the dependencies in my workspace's package.xml files are supported in the new version without having to install ubuntu 24.04 onto my computer?

Not sure if there exists something inbuilt for that, but you can use something similar to GitHub actions. Where you upload all the packages to the repo and build it.
Another option can be to use docker and put all the packages in docker and try building it there.
Recently, I have also come across this tool which allows you to run GitHub workflow actions locally. You can give it a try and
